# Monkey patch Testcafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, monkeypatching

I'm trying to monkey patch Testcafe in the following manner:

1. Add custom methods available in all tests

```
t.patch.typeText = async (selector, txt, opts) => {
  await t.click(selector);
  await t.typeText(selector, txt, opts);
}
/* This didn't work */
```

2. Run custom code on every page load.

```
await t.click(Selector('a[href="/no_thing"]');
await t.onPageLoaded(someCustomFunction())
```

Didn't find much online googling these, any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test controller instance (`t`) is different in each test, so you cannot patch it this way.

Regarding the two scenarios you have described, try the following approaches:

#### Scenario 1

Create helper functions with actions you need to reuse. You can define helpers in a separate file and then import this file to the tests whenever you need these functions:

*helpers.js*

```js
import { t } from 'testcafe';

export async function type(selector, txt, opts) => {
    await t
        .click(selector)
        .typeText(selector, txt, opts);
}
```

*test.js*

```js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import { type } from './helpers.js';
   
fixture `My Fixture`
    .page `https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/`;
 
test('My Test', async t => {
    await type(Selector('#element'), 'text', { replace: true });
});
```

Please also note that the `t.typeText` action clicks the target input before it types text. You shouldn't need a separate click action to focus the input.

For more information about helper functions, see [Create Helpers](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/extract-reusable-test-code/create-helpers.html).

We have plans to support custom actions that would better address your use case in the future releases. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1535) for details.

#### Scenario 2

TestCafe can inject custom scripts into every page visited during the test run, test or fixture. These scripts are injected into the `<head>` tag and executed in a usual manner.

Create a file with the scripts you need to inject:

*script.js*

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // this code runs on each page when it is loaded
});
```

Then [inject these scripts](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/inject-scripts-into-tested-pages.html#add-client-scripts-to-all-tests) with one of the following methods:

*Command line interface*

```sh
testcafe chrome test.js --client-scripts script.js
```

*Programming interface*

```js
runner.clientScripts('script.js');
```

*Configuration file*

```
{
    "clientScripts": "script.js"
}
```

For more information about script injection, see [Inject Scripts into Tested Pages](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/inject-scripts-into-tested-pages.html).